# How can I pass a dynamic URL in a POST request via jQuery?

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to do this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/accounts/{{ request.user.username }}/profile_listview",
            data: { entryname:id },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response.success);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

But I need to find a solution to pass in the dynamic URL since Django template variables won't work in this scenario.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable you need to pass is always the same (like `request.user.username` will be always the same for one user) you could render a javascript object containing all the options that you need to access to build your url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var __MYAPP_CONFIG__ = {
      username: JSON.stringify({{ request.user.username }})
    };
</script>
```

Then, in your script you could bring that dynamic part in by accessing `my_app.username`.

```
$.ajax({
    # ...
    url: "/accounts/" + window.__MYAPP_CONFIG__.username + "/profile_listview",
    # ...
});
```

What I like about this approach is that it (in my opinion) provides a rather generic structure for projects that grow with time. For sites that are big enough I mostly end up having one configuration object with a structure like `my_project.my_app1.options`, `my_project.my_app2.options`, etc. That way all apps that might need it are namespaced and I have a central location where I know to find my options.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use a html5's data attribute, something like:

```
<a class="delete_button" ... data-url="{% url 'my_url_name' username=request.user.username %}">Delete</a>
```

This way, is more DRY.

Then, in the script, you use that data as the url to post to:

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).data('url'),
    data: { entryname:id },
    success: function(response){
       alert(response.success);
    }
 });`